# How do I put other people as friends on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

My sibling somehow added me as a friend on YouTube, but I don't know how. I would ask, but I am wanting to know for to contact others for a mini movie series. So I am hoping someone can tell me an updated version on how to add a friend on YouTube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open YouTube
- Click on messages icon and open one dialog box
- In Dialog box click on Friends option
- After click on friends option show Add connection option click and send 
  invite link to other people

[image]

[image]