# How do I add other people as friends on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I tried 2 times the method described at [How do I put other people as friends on YouTube?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/120312/how-do-i-put-other-people-as-friends-on-youtube/133477) and this method has failed both times (indeed, otherwise this post would be a total waste of resources).

The first time that I tried it, I was on the 'Home' section of YouTube and the second time I was on the person's channel.

Any clues/solutions to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When on mobile, there used to be a button to add friends. However, they’re getting rid of the feature on the 18th so it’s not longer possible to add anyone.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Do you have any idea(s) on how I can grant someone the privilege to view private video(s) ?